# About Akasha Maha bhuta

Tags: panchabhoota

I would like to understand
about Akasha maha bhuta. It is said that sound is a property of Akasha Maha bhuta, which means if Akasha exist, sound should be there. If we take an example of the flute, there are lots of space and holes in there. But only when we blow into the flute, sound is created. So, should we call the space inside flute as Akasha or Akasha is created only when we blow into it?
Also, please suggest any authentic text to understand about pancha maha bhutas.
Thanks

Comment: When a Galtons whistle is blown, it is not heard by a human unlike a flute .. (though some animals like dogs are receptive to such sounds in ultrasonic ranges).So , even at  gross level, one can't say sound is not there  if it is not heard. Panchatanmatras(subtle elements) are the causatives of Panchabhutas . Here Shabda tanmatra is the primordial vibration, subtle( which can't be perceived).It is "ever existent" since creation., mother of akasha. So there is never a case Shabda tanmatra is not there during manifestation ,but  it can't be perceived.

Comment: Other tanamatras / Panchabhutas are its evolutes.Pancikarana by Sri Shankarabhagavadpada, details Pancha tanamatras/bhutas . Idea of the same can also be gotten from a potion of most of the puranas, Vedas.